# angularjs: directive link function called twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating my first directive and I'm running into some strange behaviour. **The console.log() in my link-function is called twice.** I've googled for some solutions, but I don't see how I need to change my code to change the behaviour...

My index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>GCSE Directive TEST</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="gcseTest">

  <google-image-search query="Test query"></google-image-search>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="gcse-directive.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

gcse-directive:

```
angular.module('gcseTest', [])
  .directive('googleImageSearch', [ function(){
      return {
        scope: {
          query: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'gcse-popup.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          $scope.search = function(){
            console.log("Gebruik query in link-functie: " + $scope.query);
            return "Gebruik query via popup: " + $scope.query;
          }
        }
      };
  }]);
```

gcse-popup.html:

```
<div>
  <h1>Directive Test</h1>
  {{search(query)}}
</div>
```

Can somebody explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive link function isn't getting called twice, its `search` function is getting called twice. The reason behind it is getting called twice as, you have used `search` function directly as in view bindings, so whenever digest cycle run your view binding gets evaluated. In this case digest cycle gets ran twice, that's why your `search` function ran twice and you can see `console` printed twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also explain to me what the best practice is to implement what I want to do (= show the result of a function in "link" directly in the view bindings)?

Comment: @bits can you explain your whole scenario? So that I can suggest correct way of doing it..

Comment: In my app, I want a button which opens a popup with results from google custom search engine (based on a value in the parent's controller. Once the user clicks on one of the results, the url is written to the parent's controller and shown in a textbox. The the popup must be reusable, so I wanted to put  this in a directive. The button and textbox are in the directive's parent (unless you advise otherwise :)). In my code above, I'm only starting with my directive, so it does not (yet) do what I've described here:)